# Puzzling Motivation for posting

Tags: discussion

On other Stack exchange sites users ask questions which they need help with in hope of getting answers. This site is unique in that questions/challenges that the OP knows the solution to, are being actively posted and on topic.

Personally this is what draws me to this site - a place where I can discover new puzzles to try to solve. I'm wondering how does this impact the traditional Q&A format? Should we have a tag for people wanting help vs. posting challenges?

Comment: You know meta tags are actively discouraged by Jeff Atwood?  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion it impacts the Q&A format by making it very easy to make lots of less quality puzzles instead of a single high quality one. (Guess who makes more rep?) A good puzzle could only get 10 upvotes due to less people upvoting on the site.  <s>Also I have found that Ops wanting help is much less common than OPs with a riddle, so I would propose only a single "need-help" tag for OPs that dont know the answer to their riddles.</s>  Now that I think of it, what is the difference between a op that knows the answer and a op that doesn't? I don't think "OP-doesn't-know-the-answer" tags would be necessary, and popularizing such a tag would be a nightmare.